# How to pass a url as a url parameter when there is a question mark in it?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url-parameters

I am using this line to pass the a `url`, `main_id` and `user_tag_list` to the handler:

```
self.response.out.write("""

<a href="/tc?url=%s&main_id=%s&user_tag_list=%s" title="edit tag set">edit tag set</a>

""" %
(item.url, main_id, item.tag_list))
```

this works fine except that when there is already a question mark in the passed `url` (the first parameter) I can no longer get the `main_id` with

```
main_id = self.request.get("main_id")
```

in the target handler, instead I get the error

```
m = Main.get_by_id(int(main_id))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just want to use `urllib.quote`

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.quote('http://www.google.com?q=Zombie+Apocalypse')
'http%3A//www.google.com%3Fq%3DZombie%2BApocalypse'
```

So:

```
urllib.quote(item.url)
```

Answer (score 1):

`urllib.quote` ought to help with this.